# Wide to Long with unequal number of repeated measurements SPSS

Tags: reshape, spss

I want to Reconstruct dataset from wide format to long format for analysis in mixed models. Some variables have 0M, 3M, 6M, 9M, 12M repeated measurements every 3 months for a
12M follow-up, and some have 12 measurements one every month. When I use VARTOCASES, how do I fill in the sub-command index? If I record (5) it is not suitable for repeated measurements every month and so on if I register (12) it will not be suitable for measurements every 3 months. What do you suggest?

```
VARSTOCASES
    / make WEIGHT from WEIGHT0M WEIGHT3M WEIGHT6M WEIGHT9M WEIGHT12M
    / make HB from HB1 to HB12
    / index = TIME (5)
    / keep = ID.
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to take care of the imbalance between the two variable groups - `varstocases` won't work at all until they are balanced (you can't have two `/make ... from` commands with different numbers of variables).
One way to balance them could be to create dummy variables to fill the gaps.

A couple of notes before the code:

1. Variable names like `WEIGHT0M WEIGHT3M WEIGHT6M ...` don't work as
   well with [the **TO**
   keyword](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/24.0.0?topic=variables-keyword#syn_variables_to),
   so in the syntax below I create a completely new series and "import"
   the values from the old variables.
2. It seems to be you actually have 13 data points and not 12 - since
   variable WEIGHT0M represents point 0M which isn't represented in the
   `HB1 to HB12` series - so we need to create a dummy for that too.

```
compute WEIGHTM0=WEIGHT0M.
vector WEIGHTM(12).
do repeat /nw=WEIGHTM3 WEIGHTM6 WEIGHTM9 WEIGHTM12 /orig=WEIGHT3M WEIGHT6M WEIGHT9M WEIGHT12M.
   compute nw=orig.
end repeat.
compute HB0=$sysmis.
    
VARSTOCASES
    / make WEIGHT from WEIGHTM0 to WEIGHTM12
    / make HB from HB0 to HB12
    / index = TIME (13).
```

This will end up with empty values in the `WEIGHT` column for time points 1,2,4,5 etc'. Alternatively you could choose to put values there, for example you could copy the value of point 0 to points 1, 2, the value of point 3 to points 4, 5 etc'. You can do it by extending the above loop, or you could use the following - after the `varstocases`:

```
sort cases by ID index.
if $casenum>1 and ID=lag(ID) and missing(WEIGHT) WEIGHT=lag(WEIGHT).
```